# How to run tasks under managed identity user accounts in Azure Batch

Tags: azure, active-directory, batch-processing, azure-batch, azure-managed-identity

We can run tasks in azure batch under

1. Auto-user accounts
2. A named user account

But they are not AD users. 
I like to run my tasks under AD account user so the task will have all permissions that the manage user does.

Comment: Can you provide any additional details? The purpose of managed identities is to ensure the identity (service) is the one providing the access/executing not sure why you'd want to execute tasks as a managed identity but not executed by the managed identity

Comment: @DreadedFrost, I like the task in the batch job run under an AD account. Thats it. For example my account has access to azure KeyVault  so If the task run under my account then it can access to KeyVault without more configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Azure batch does not support managed identity for now. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities) I found list of resources in azure that support managed identity.

I installed certificates on my nodes to be able to access the keyvalut.

Comment: You can assign a managed identity to a batch and add it to the key-vault, but I can't figure out how to access that managed identity from a pool account in the batch. Maybe that isn't supported yet.